# What does consumer LAG mean in Consumer Group

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm observing that Kafka Consumer is inconsistently not able to receive the messages when Producer trying to send it. When i checked kafka consumer , there are LAG values seen :

```
 docker run   --net=host   --rm <docker image> kafka-consumer-groups --zookeeper localhost:2181  --describe --group mgmt_testing

GROUP                          TOPIC    PARTITION   CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET    LAG             OWNER
mgmt_testing          mgmt_testing         0           44              44              0               mgmt_testing_aws-us-east-1-mr3-10-10-8-218-1561090200381-21858516-0
mgmt_testing          mgmt_testing          1          35              35              0               mgmt_testing_aws-us-east-1-mr3-10-10-8-218-1561090200381-21858516-0
mgmt_testing          mgmt_testing          2          39              39              0               mgmt_testing_aws-us-east-1-mr3-10-10-8-218-1561090200381-21858516-0
mgmt_testing          mgmt_testing          3          37              37              0               mgmt_testing_aws-us-east-1-mr3-10-10-8-218-1561090200381-21858516-0
mgmt_testing          mgmt_testing          4          25              38              13              mgmt_testing_aws-us-east-1-mr3-10-10-8-218-1561090200381-21858516-0
mgmt_testing          mgmt_testing          5          458             666             208             mgmt_testing_aws-us-east-1-mr3-10-10-8-218-1561090200381-21858516-0
mgmt_testing          mgmt_testing          6          808167          808181          14              mgmt_testing_aws-us-east-1-mr3-10-10-8-218-1561090200381-21858516-0
mgmt_testing          mgmt_testing          7          434028          434041          13              mgmt_testing_aws-us-east-1-mr3-10-10-8-218-1561090200381-21858516-0
```

What does LAG mean here ? And will this be the reason that consumer is not able to receive the messages?

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, lag is the fact that there will always be some delay between publish a message to a Kafka broker and consuming it. There's a good description on sematext's website: https://sematext.com/blog/kafka-consumer-lag-offsets-monitoring/