# How to detect if all consumer instances under a single group have consumed all Kafka messages from a particular topic?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am currently working on de-bulking file feed (daily one time) into single messages and posting in Kafka topic. Consumers start processing as soon as the message is available. This is in Kubernetes environment in OCP.

I need to perform a Job once all the consumer instances have finished consuming those messages in the Kafka Topic for that day.

How this can be captured in microservices built using Java?

Answer (score 0):

Your consumer is able to know its own lag, in relation to the end of the topic. This would be the best option since when lag == 0 (which may never happen if the topic is actively produced to), you can send some external event to trigger any downstream workflow.

Otherwise, you will need to run tools like Burrow or Kafka-Exporter in Prometheus, then poll the API of those, on some interval to get lag (again, may never reach zero)

Comment: The producer produces only once, not on continuous basis. Imagine, they are producing 3 millions messages in a span of 1 hour. Thats it for that day. The lag option, I didn't get quite well. Can you explain more on it pls.

Comment: When a consumer starts, it has 3 million records to read. That's it's lag... If it consumes 1 million, it has a lag of 2 million... https://stackoverflow.com/q/57344627/2308683  So, you keep track of that, and if/when it reaches zero, that's the only point when you can possibly know you're "done consuming". Kafka itself doesn't track this for consumers, or push any event when they are complete, only consumers can know themselves